# Is it safe to apply new lifecycle policy to existing AWS S3 bucket with huge number of items?

Tags: amazon-s3

We have a huge S3 bucket with some billions of items inside. For now it doesn't have any item lifecycle policy applied, so items are stored forever. We want to purge items which are older than half a year and do it on a regular basis further. Using S3 lifecycle policy such task seems easy, but is it safe (in terms of performance and availability) to apply a policy to existing huge bucket or lifecycle policies should be safely applied to new buckets only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a safe operation, as far as performance is concerned, regardless of bucket size or number of objects impacted, because lifecycle policies are handled asynchronously, in the background, in stages.

> **Expiring Objects: General Considerations**
>
> When an object reaches the end of its lifetime, Amazon S3 queues it for removal and removes it asynchronously. There may be a delay between the expiration date and the date at which Amazon S3 removes an object. You are not charged for storage time associated with an object that has expired.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html

Comment: Thx Michael, I expected such an answer, but It's a bit scary to push the button for production bucket when you are not sure :)

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced performance issues, especially with EMR, JetS3t, and S3 console, when using lifecycles to delete billions of objects on versioning enabled buckets.  A deleted current version has a delete marker object added, and becomes a previous version, then the previous version is cleaned up later by the lifecycle's previous version delete setting.  The delete marker is another object added that must be filtered in the console or bucket listings.  So we get 2 times the number of objects until they are all deleted.  We also pay standard charges for the previous version storage until it is deleted.

Any application that lists objects may need to filter current, delete markers, and previous versions.  I found the S3 console would hang until i selected "Versions: Show".  In some cases hadoop 1.x and JetS3t would timeout until most delete markers previous versions were cleaned up, especially from the bucket root.

For versioning enabled buckets I recommend you start deleting gradually by setting the lifecycle interval large then reduce the interval over time.  I also found using lifecycles is not instantaneous and it takes several days (at least) for lots of objects to be removed.

I use http://www.insight4storage.com/ from AWS Marketplace to monitor my  storage types and versions per bucket and prefix.  It helped me track lifecycle progress over time by showing the current and previous versions, IA, RRS, and Glacier storage by prefix and per bucket.